# How do I display the value before it changes in a for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, output

" The program should start by asking how many rooms the property has. Use a loop to calculate the Rectangular Area (SQF) of each room. Display the SQF for each room and the total SQF of the property."

So, I Finally got my code to work, except I cannot get 1 thing:
Example of issue: Say I enter 2 rooms, then for the first room i put in 10 x 2 which is an area of 20, then for the second room i put 8 x 2 which is 16. 
Well When the code is displaying the information at the end it just shows 16 as the area for both rooms, and i'm assuming this is because that is the last area that was calculated.
At the very end it shows a total area of 36 so i know I'm close to the right path. but i cannot for the life of me figure this out.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class PropertySF
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

   double length = 0,    // The room's length
          width = 0,     // The room's width
          area = 0;      // The room's area
   int numRoom;          // for number of rooms
   double roomSF = 0;    // square footage for each room
   double totalSF = 0;   // Total square footage



  // Get the amount of rooms
  numRoom = getRooms();

  // Get the rooms dimentions from the user.
  for (double maxRoom = 1; maxRoom <= numRoom; maxRoom++)
  {
      length = getLength();

      // Get the rooms's width from the user.
      width = getWidth();

      // Get the rooms's area.
      area = getArea(length, width);
      totalSF += area;
 }

  // Display the room data.
  displayData(numRoom, totalSF, area);

  System.exit(0);
}

public static int getRooms()
 {
   //See CL 5-10 Page 298
   String input;        //For input
   //get input from user
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of rooms in the 
                                         the house: "); //Line 37
   return Integer.parseInt(input); //Line 45- 48
  }

/**
*The getLength prompts user for the length of the room
*@return value entered by user.
*/
public static double getLength()
{
   //See CL 5-10 Page 298
   String input;        //For input
   //get input from user
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the length of the room:");
   return Double.parseDouble(input); //Line 45- 48
}

/**
*The getWidth prompts user for the Width of the room
*@return value entered by user.
*/
public static double getWidth()
{
   //See CL 5-10 Page 298
   String input;        //For input
   //get input from user
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the width of the room:");
   return Double.parseDouble(input); //Line 45-48
} 

/**
* The getArea method will calculate the room's area
* @param length the room's length
* @param with the room's width
* @return the area of the room
*/
public static double getArea(double length, double width)
{
   return length * width;
}

/**
* The displayData method displays the rooms data.
* 
*/

public static void displayData(double numRoom,
                              double totalSF,
                              double area)
{
   for (double maxRoom  = 1; maxRoom <= numRoom; maxRoom++)
   {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
     String.format("The Square footage for room %f is %f,\n" +
                                "The total SQF is: %f \n", maxRoom, area,
 totalSF));
   }                             
 }

}
```

Comment: It's because you don't "displayData" until after the loop finishes.  You will only see the last result.  Just move that line inside the loop.

Comment: @durbnpoisn AHHH you're amazing. Thank you so much. I've been at this stupid thing for forever. I got rid of the pointless loop in the "displayData" and just put the "displayData" in the loop at the top. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `area` is only being passed into the displayData function once, so there is only one value in the loop. One possible solution is to pass in an area array and then loop through that as you loop through the rooms, but I think the better solution is to just display one room at a time in displayData (so remove the loop from displayData, and move the function call into the loop in main) and move the totalSF display to another function (if you don't want to show a running total of totalSF).

Answer (score 0):

The Possible solution is define area as a array or [list](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)(if size is unknown), Store values in array and display it. Though there are several ways to do it.